# String in fourth column in C++ object declaration

Tags: c++, static, declaration

I am mostly a Java programmer with some C++ training, now facing a complicated bit of C++ code.

There are a series of static variables declared with a four-term declaration that has not appeared in any of my c++ tutorials.

It takes the form

```
static VAR var ("var");
```

So VAR is the class, var the name and...what is the string at the end? If this were Java I would say, the string looks like an argument being passed to the VAR constructor, except that it would be wrong because the object is static so a constructor is never called. So, is the string some sort of C++ constructor call?

Comment: Please forget new - in c++ new is an allocation, but a construction on stack without new is fine (and preferable for small objects).

Comment: Constructors are called for static objects too - how else would they get constructed?

Comment: There should be no issues declaring a initializing a static variable in this way in c++.

Comment: All a c++ object needs is a declared type and a defined size and location, than you can construct an (static/stack/dynamic allocated) object (leaving abstract classes aside).

Comment: Is this another stack / heap distinction -- new would put it on the heap, called like this it is on stack?

Comment: @barnhillec: class I { public: int i; }; - feel free to put int on the stack, just like an ordinary integer

Comment: I am quite sure that this is in **all** of your C++ tutorials....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VAR` is the type (might be a class).

`var` is the variable name.

If some brackets follow, that is what is passed to the constructor. If that declaration is at global scope: It is called right before `main()` is called. If that declaration is inside a function: It is called at the first time it executes that part of the function.

Note that `static` is not exactly the same in C++ and Java, although they are similar.